# How to keep while loop going but get the same random number but change after completion

Tags: python, loops

This question is difficult to explain, I hope that title doesn't confuse people.

So I have to make the user guess a number from 1 - 100, and if the user guesses the number correctly, I want it to restart the game but generate a new number and display the welcome message again. Also the user can only try 10 times and then have a game over message appear.
I am stuck trying to display the new message, generate a new number, have the number be the same throughout the loop and fail the user at 10 tries.

I am sorry again if this is confusing.

This is what I have:

```
import random
import time
def getInput():
    x = random.randrange(100)
    print(x) # for testing

    print("***Welcome! Guess and try to find a number between 1 and 100!***")
    while True:
        userGuess = int(input("Enter Your Guess: "))

        if (userGuess > x):
            print("Lower! Enter Again: ")

        elif (userGuess < x):
            print("Higher! Enter Again: ")
        elif (userGuess > 100):
            print("Guess must be between 1 and 100")
        elif (userGuess < 1):
            print("Guess must be greater then 0")
        elif (userGuess == x):
            print("You win!")
            time.sleep(3)
            continue

def main():
    getInput()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the loop starts you need to generate a new random number then reset the number of tries to 0

```
import random
import time
def getInput():
    x = random.randrange(100)
    print(x) # for testing

    print("***Welcome! Guess and try to find a number between 1 and 100!***")
    tries = 0 # we need a variabe to see how many tries the user has had
    while True:
        userGuess = int(input("Try "+str(tries + 1)+" Enter Your Guess: "))

        if (userGuess == x):
            print("You win!")
            print("***Think you can win again? Guess and try to find a number between 1 and 100!***")
            x = random.randrange(100)
            tries = 0 # reset tries
            print(x) # we need a new random number for the user to guess
            time.sleep(3)            
            continue

        elif (userGuess > x):
            print("Lower! Enter Again: ")
        elif (userGuess < x):
            print("Higher! Enter Again: ")

        if (userGuess > 100):
            print("Guess must be between 1 and 100")
        elif (userGuess < 1):
            print("Guess must be greater then 0")
        else:
            tries = tries + 1 # add 1 to tries unless they make an invalid guess
            if tries == 10:
                print("<<GAME OVER>>")
                break # end


def main():
    getInput()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def getInput():
  for i in range(10):
  #loop body

  return "Game Over."
```

If I'm interpreting you want to end after 10 guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep the changes to minimum for you to easily understand, see @Tom's answer for a better way

```
import random
import time

def startNewGame():
    x = random.randrange(100)
    print(x) # for testing

    print("***Welcome! Guess and try to find a number between 1 and 100!***")
    numberOfTries = 0
    while numberOfTries<10:
        userGuess = int(input("Enter Your Guess: "))
        numberOfTries += 1
        if (userGuess > x):
            print("Lower! Enter Again: ")
        elif (userGuess < x):
            print("Higher! Enter Again: ")
        elif (userGuess > 100):
            print("Guess must be between 1 and 100")
        elif (userGuess < 1):
            print("Guess must be greater then 0")
        elif (userGuess == x):
            print("You win!")
            time.sleep(3)
            return
    print("You Lose!")
    time.sleep(3)

def main():
    startNewGame()
    while(True):
        again = input("Would you like to play again?(yes/no) ")
        if again == "yes":
            startNewGame()
        elif again == "no":
            break


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would suggest to do it. I added comments with three hashes where I made changes:

```
import random
import time
def playMany():
    def play():
        x = random.randrange(100)
        print(x) # for testing

        print("***Welcome! Guess and try to find a number between 1 and 100!***")
        for attempt in range(10): ### try 10 times at the most
            userGuess = int(input("Enter Your Guess: "))

            ### change the order of the tests:
            if (userGuess > 100):
                print("Guess must be between 1 and 100")
            elif (userGuess < 1):
                print("Guess must be greater then 0")
            elif (userGuess > x):
                print("Lower!") ### Don't ask to "enter" here
            elif (userGuess < x):
                print("Higher!")
            else: ### no need to test for equality: it is the only possibility left
                print("You win!")
                return True ### Exit play() with True (to play again)
        ### Deal with too many wrong guesses
        print('Too many wrong guesses. Game over')
        return False

    while play(): ### Keep repeating the game until False is returned
        time.sleep(3) ### Move sleep here

def main():
    playMany() ### Use a more telling function name

main()
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Dz1g/5).

Answer (score 0):

Here if one more way of doing it:

```
import random
import time

def matchGuess(randNumber, userGuess):
    if   userGuess > 100         : print "Guest must be between 1 and 100"
    elif userGuess < 0           : print "Guest must be greater than 0"
    elif userGuess > randNumber  : print "Lower! Enter Again:"
    elif userGuess < randNumber  : print "Higher! Enter Again:"
    elif userGuess == randNumber : print "You win!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "***Welcome! Guess and try to find a number between 1 and 100!***"
    for i in range(10):
        userGuess  = int(raw_input("Enter Your Guess:"))
        randNumber = random.randrange(100)
        matchGuess(randNumber, userGuess)
```